# How can I add generate more conversations automatic when typing the int field numbers?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using UnityEditor.IMGUI.Controls;
using UnityEngine;


namespace UnityEditor.TreeViewExamples
{

    class CustomHeightWindow : EditorWindow
    {
        [NonSerialized] bool m_Initialized;
        [SerializeField] TreeViewState m_TreeViewState; // Serialized in the window layout file so it survives assembly reloading
        SearchField m_SearchField;
        CustomHeightTreeView m_TreeView;
        MyTreeAsset m_MyTreeAsset;
        SimpleTreeView simple_m_TreeView;

        private GUIStyle currentStyle = null;
        static int numofconversations;
        static int oldnumofconversations;

        [MenuItem("TreeView Examples/Custom Row Heights")]
        public static CustomHeightWindow GetWindow()
        {
            var window = GetWindow<CustomHeightWindow>();
            window.titleContent = new GUIContent("Custom Heights");
            window.Focus();
            window.Repaint();

            oldnumofconversations = numofconversations;

            return window;
        }

        [OnOpenAsset]
        public static bool OnOpenAsset(int instanceID, int line)
        {
            var myTreeAsset = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID) as MyTreeAsset;
            if (myTreeAsset != null)
            {
                var window = GetWindow();
                window.SetTreeAsset(myTreeAsset);
                return true;
            }
            return false; // we did not handle the open
        }

        void SetTreeAsset(MyTreeAsset myTreeAsset)
        {
            m_MyTreeAsset = myTreeAsset;
            m_Initialized = false;
        }

        Rect treeViewRect
        {
            get { return new Rect(20, 70, position.width - 40, position.height - 100); }
        }

        Rect toolbarRect
        {
            get { return new Rect(20f, 10f, position.width - 40f, 20f); }
        }

        Rect bottomToolbarRect
        {
            get { return new Rect(20f, position.height - 18f, position.width - 40f, 16f); }
        }

        void InitIfNeeded()
        {
            if (!m_Initialized)
            {
                // Check if it already exists (deserialized from window layout file or scriptable object)
                if (m_TreeViewState == null)
                    m_TreeViewState = new TreeViewState();

                var treeModel = new TreeModel<MyTreeElement>(GetData());
                m_TreeView = new CustomHeightTreeView(m_TreeViewState, treeModel);

                m_SearchField = new SearchField();
                m_SearchField.downOrUpArrowKeyPressed += m_TreeView.SetFocusAndEnsureSelectedItem;

                m_Initialized = true;
            }
        }

        IList<MyTreeElement> GetData()
        {
            if (m_MyTreeAsset != null && m_MyTreeAsset.treeElements != null && m_MyTreeAsset.treeElements.Count > 0)
                return m_MyTreeAsset.treeElements;

            // generate some test data
            return MyTreeElementGenerator.GenerateRandomTree(numofconversations);
        }

        void OnSelectionChange()
        {
            if (!m_Initialized)
                return;

            var myTreeAsset = Selection.activeObject as MyTreeAsset;
            if (myTreeAsset != null && myTreeAsset != m_MyTreeAsset)
            {
                m_MyTreeAsset = myTreeAsset;
                m_TreeView.treeModel.SetData(GetData());
                m_TreeView.Reload();
            }
        }

        void OnGUI()
        {
            if(oldnumofconversations != numofconversations)
            {
                m_Initialized = true;
                oldnumofconversations = numofconversations;
            }

            InitIfNeeded();

            SearchBar(toolbarRect);
            DoTreeView(treeViewRect);
            BottomToolBar(bottomToolbarRect);
            DoFields();

            DoTreeView();
        }

        void SearchBar(Rect rect)
        {
            m_TreeView.searchString = m_SearchField.OnGUI(rect, m_TreeView.searchString);
        }

        void DoTreeView(Rect rect)
        {
            m_TreeView.OnGUI(rect);
        }

        void BottomToolBar(Rect rect)
        {
            GUILayout.BeginArea(rect);

            using (new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
            {
                var style = "miniButton";
                if (GUILayout.Button("Expand All", style))
                {
                    m_TreeView.ExpandAll();
                }

                if (GUILayout.Button("Collapse All", style))
                {
                    m_TreeView.CollapseAll();
                }
            }

            GUILayout.EndArea();
        }

        void DoFields()
        {
            DrawBox(new Rect(20, 35, position.width - 40, 30),"", Color.white);
            numofconversations = EditorGUI.IntField(new Rect(187, 43, 50, 15), numofconversations);
            GUI.Label(new Rect(37, 41, 150, 15), "Number of conversations");
        }

        void DrawBox(Rect position, string content, Color color)
        {
            Color oldColor = GUI.color;

            GUI.color = color;
            GUI.Box(position, content);

            GUI.color = oldColor;
        }

        void DoTreeView()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In the top I added two new static variables :

```
static int numofconversations;
static int oldnumofconversations;
```

Then inside the static method GetWindow I did :

```
oldnumofconversations = numofconversations;
```

Then inside the OnGUI :

```
if(oldnumofconversations != numofconversations)
            {
                m_Initialized = true;
                oldnumofconversations = numofconversations;
            }
```

But using a break point showing that oldnumofconversations is all the time have the same number like numofconversations when changing the number in the int field.

Comment: Because `OnGUI` gets called for several times in a frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is working :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;
using UnityEditor.IMGUI.Controls;
using UnityEngine;


namespace UnityEditor.TreeViewExamples
{

    class CustomHeightWindow : EditorWindow
    {
        [NonSerialized] bool m_Initialized;
        [SerializeField] TreeViewState m_TreeViewState; // Serialized in the window layout file so it survives assembly reloading
        SearchField m_SearchField;
        CustomHeightTreeView m_TreeView;
        MyTreeAsset m_MyTreeAsset;
        SimpleTreeView simple_m_TreeView;

        private GUIStyle currentStyle = null;
        static int numofconversations = 10;
        static int oldnumofconversations;

        [MenuItem("TreeView Examples/Custom Row Heights")]
        public static CustomHeightWindow GetWindow()
        {
            var window = GetWindow<CustomHeightWindow>();
            window.titleContent = new GUIContent("Custom Heights");
            window.Focus();
            window.Repaint();

            oldnumofconversations = numofconversations;

            return window;
        }

        [OnOpenAsset]
        public static bool OnOpenAsset(int instanceID, int line)
        {
            var myTreeAsset = EditorUtility.InstanceIDToObject(instanceID) as MyTreeAsset;
            if (myTreeAsset != null)
            {
                var window = GetWindow();
                window.SetTreeAsset(myTreeAsset);
                return true;
            }
            return false; // we did not handle the open
        }

        void SetTreeAsset(MyTreeAsset myTreeAsset)
        {
            m_MyTreeAsset = myTreeAsset;
            m_Initialized = false;
        }

        Rect treeViewRect
        {
            get { return new Rect(20, 70, position.width - 40, position.height - 100); }
        }

        Rect toolbarRect
        {
            get { return new Rect(20f, 10f, position.width - 40f, 20f); }
        }

        Rect bottomToolbarRect
        {
            get { return new Rect(20f, position.height - 18f, position.width - 40f, 16f); }
        }

        void InitIfNeeded()
        {
            if (!m_Initialized)
            {
                // Check if it already exists (deserialized from window layout file or scriptable object)
                if (m_TreeViewState == null)
                    m_TreeViewState = new TreeViewState();

                var treeModel = new TreeModel<MyTreeElement>(GetData());
                m_TreeView = new CustomHeightTreeView(m_TreeViewState, treeModel);

                m_SearchField = new SearchField();
                m_SearchField.downOrUpArrowKeyPressed += m_TreeView.SetFocusAndEnsureSelectedItem;

                m_Initialized = true;
            }
        }

        IList<MyTreeElement> GetData()
        {
            if (m_MyTreeAsset != null && m_MyTreeAsset.treeElements != null && m_MyTreeAsset.treeElements.Count > 0)
                return m_MyTreeAsset.treeElements;

            // generate some test data
            return MyTreeElementGenerator.GenerateRandomTree(numofconversations);
        }

        void OnSelectionChange()
        {
            if (!m_Initialized)
                return;

            var myTreeAsset = Selection.activeObject as MyTreeAsset;
            if (myTreeAsset != null && myTreeAsset != m_MyTreeAsset)
            {
                m_MyTreeAsset = myTreeAsset;
                m_TreeView.treeModel.SetData(GetData());
                m_TreeView.Reload();
            }
        }

        void OnGUI()
        {
            if(oldnumofconversations != numofconversations)
            {
                m_Initialized = false;
                oldnumofconversations = numofconversations;
            }

            InitIfNeeded();

            SearchBar(toolbarRect);
            DoTreeView(treeViewRect);
            BottomToolBar(bottomToolbarRect);
            DoFields();

            DoTreeView();
        }

        void SearchBar(Rect rect)
        {
            m_TreeView.searchString = m_SearchField.OnGUI(rect, m_TreeView.searchString);
        }

        void DoTreeView(Rect rect)
        {
            m_TreeView.OnGUI(rect);
        }

        void BottomToolBar(Rect rect)
        {
            GUILayout.BeginArea(rect);

            using (new EditorGUILayout.HorizontalScope())
            {
                var style = "miniButton";
                if (GUILayout.Button("Expand All", style))
                {
                    m_TreeView.ExpandAll();
                }

                if (GUILayout.Button("Collapse All", style))
                {
                    m_TreeView.CollapseAll();
                }
            }

            GUILayout.EndArea();
        }

        void DoFields()
        {
            DrawBox(new Rect(20, 35, position.width - 40, 30),"", Color.white);
            numofconversations = EditorGUI.IntField(new Rect(187, 43, 50, 15), numofconversations);
            GUI.Label(new Rect(37, 41, 150, 15), "Number of conversations");
        }

        void DrawBox(Rect position, string content, Color color)
        {
            Color oldColor = GUI.color;

            GUI.color = color;
            GUI.Box(position, content);

            GUI.color = oldColor;
        }

        void DoTreeView()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I had to set the variable m_Initialized = false; to false inside the OnGUI :

```
if(oldnumofconversations != numofconversations)
            {
                m_Initialized = false;
                oldnumofconversations = numofconversations;
            }
```